# GFlops for IBM Power8 processor

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, cpu, performance

What is the number of GFlops per cpu cycle for IBM Power8?

Flops per cpu cycle is obtained as ( number of double precision floating point numbers fitting into one vector processing unit (if any) ) * (# Vector processing units) * 2 (if FMA is supported).

What is it for a Power8 processor? I read that Power* currently has one vector processing unit per core, and it is supporting 4 double precision numbers in it. so for instance for Power S822LC model 8355-GTA I find a peak performance of 
(8 cores) * (3.32 GHz) * (4*2) = 212 GFlops per socket. Could someone confirm? In my calculation, 4*2 is the number of Flops per cpu cycle, 4 is the number of double precision number in register and the factor 2 is for FMA support.

Answer (score 1):

If you like, you can Google "Power 8 Processor flops".

If you're too lazy to do your own basic research, [this](http://www.hpcwire.com/2015/06/02/cpu-benchmarking-haswell-versus-power8/) suggests about 600 to 700 GFLOPs/sec. Note that performance benchmarks always reflect, to some degree, the design of the benchmark software.

Comment: I am doing the calculation as i explain in my post. I wonder if there are 8 flops per cpu cycle Double Precision (4 double fitting in one register times 2 for FMA support). Could you confirm? also if you read this http://www.altimesh-hybridizer.com/Pages/benchmarks/native/Power-8-Experiments.aspx you will see that flops is said to be 272 GFlops per socket.